# Gitignore only works on some folders

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following 2 lines in `.gitignore`

```
Valhalla/.idea/
Valhalla/target/
```

When I push to GitHub, it skips the .idea folder, but it still uploads the target folder. How can I make it also skip the target folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` only works for folders that are not already tracked.  So if you had previously committed the folder `Valhalla/target` then it's going to keep tracking it.  To resolve that do the following:

1. comment out the line `Valhalla/target` in your `.gitignore`
2. commit
3. delete the folder `Valhalla/target` in your project
4. commit
5. add back the line to your `.gitignore`
6. commit

That folder show now be untracked and if you add it back then it should be ignored and not re-added.